# code igniter's localhost mamp model works but view does not

Tags: codeigniter, view, localhost, mamp

I have a strange problem:

I am using MAMP and Codeigniter and I see that view is not showing anything on the browser. Model works and the DB is wired up. 
Here is the code that does not work on the local host:

```
$this->load->view('test/db_tester_view',$data);
```

Sadly there is no error messages!!? but here is the config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I spend 20 hours on this so your help is appreciated

Comment: Turn error reporting on.

Comment: what is the url that you're using and do you have an .htaccess file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some tips:

Make sure error reporting is on, as usual (this should be in your bootstrap file, `index.php`):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Make sure you did not disable these directives somewhere else in your script.

Windows and *NIX deal with uppercase/lowercase file names differently. Make sure your files are all normalized to lowercase to avoid problems with different operating systems.

The base url *needs* a trailing slash:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/';
// OR...
$config['base_url'] = ''; // automagic
```

If you don't require the port to be set explicitly, you can remove it.

Comment: that worked thanks...OMG ...I spend 24 hours on this! I have had  to compare the config file to the base, other issue was that I had put my directory to the htdocs...for some reason MAMP was not smart enough to grab it from another director! WOHO..it work now!

Comment: So it was the trailing slash then or filename casing?

Comment: I found this debugging method quit useful. In my case my hyphens were converted into a long hyphen when the view was called. This did the trick!